# ngmodule is not a subtype ngmoduletype

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9, angular-module

I use angular 9 and I want to do lazy load and  I do `app-routing`

```
{
    path: '', loadChildren: () => import("./components/login/login.module")//.then(m =>
     // m.LoginModule)
  }
```

and after I create login module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [LoginComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoginModuleRouting

    ],
    providers:[]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

and routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LoginComponent,

  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})


export class LoginModuleRouting { }
```

the proble is that when I call `ng serve`and I go on `http://localhost:4200/, I obtain this exception:

core.js:6237

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule '[object Module]' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]
Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule '[object Module]' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]
```

I don't knwo what it means. Anyone can help me?

Comment: It seems that you have important parts of the lazy loading route configuration commented out. Why?

Comment: has your main module `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],` defined?

Comment: could you show your app.module and main.ts?

Comment: @poopp, did you figure it out how to solve this problem

Answer (score 21):

this problem I faced was because of using standalone in my angular component and then using **loadChildren** with lazy loading route in app.routes.ts.
All I had to do was changing **loadChildren** to **loadComponent**

in app.routes.ts was

```
{
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login-page/login-page.component').then( m => m.LoginPageComponent)
},
```

and it should be

```
{
  path: 'login',
  loadComponent: () => import('./pages/login-page/login-page.component').then( m => m.LoginPageComponent)
},
```

Comment: Thank you, if you use standalone components this is it. Guess I could have figured that out by myself, but the error did not have that much information. Don't know why you got that downvote.

Comment: This should be in the angular docs as an example. Thank you.

Comment: The compiler should make a more clearer error message

Comment: Thank you so much, its working for me.
Anyways there should be elaborating message to understand it.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why but you have commented out your login module on loadChildren() here:

```
{
path: '', 
loadChildren: () => import("./components/login/login.module")//.then(m =>
     // m.LoginModule)
}
```

and it should be:

```
{
path: '', 
loadChildren: () => import("./components/login/login.module").then(m => m.LoginModule)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I also had this issue.

My problem was that I declared the NgModule without @. Adding it fixed the message.

Comment:  wow never realized how much dependent I am on the cli/autocomplete.

Answer (score 3):

I know that the original cause of this was because of promise resolution being commented out, but I wanted to add another cause since this is the highest hit on Google for this error and there are multiple causes.

This can also be caused if you're trying to use a component as a module. Using `component: MyComponentName` instead of `loadChildren: () => import('./my-component.component').then( m => m.MyComponent)` will resolve this issue too. If you intended it to be a module, you can use `ng generate module` to create a module instead if you want to delegate routing to another module.

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment the end of your lazy loaded module.

```
{
   path: '',
   loadChildren: () => import('./components/login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, this error refers to the way you're loading your modules or components!

For me that was related to how I was loading my standalone component! In fact, I was trying to load my standalone component like this:

```
   {
    path: 'shell',
    loadChildren: async () =>
     (await import('../features/shell/shell.component')).ShellComponent
   },
```

Whearase I was supposed to use loadComponent instead of loadChildren!

```
  {
    path: 'shell',
    loadComponent: async () =>
      (await import('../features/shell/shell.component')).ShellComponent
  },
```

Mainly, you should use load children for modules that define couple of routes and it's syntax is like

```
 {
        path: 'builder',
        loadChildren: (): any =>
          import('./builder/builder.module').then((m) => m.BuilderModule)
      },
```

Notice, how **import** and **then** used over here!
In order to load components lazily you can take advantage of the below syntax:

```
 {
    path: 'my-custom-path',
    loadComponent: async () =>
      (await import('../my-custom-component.component')).CustomComponent
  },
```